# Can I group a whole set of columns together in a table and use sticky?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, sticky

I have a table where I want to freeze the first three columns. It works by setting `sticky` on the columns, but that requires that I set fixed widths/lefts on them as well, which I want to avoid. Is there a way to group the first three columns and set sticky only on the group instead?

This is obvs not correct, but maybe give you an idea about what I'm after:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

colgroup {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #569CA8;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <colgroup>
          <td>Sticky 1</td>
          <td>Sticky 2</td>
          <td>Sticky 3</td>
        </colgroup>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <colgroup>
          <td>Sticky 1</td>
          <td>Sticky 2</td>
          <td>Sticky 3</td>
        </colgroup>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!